# how to config the gvim as a ide for C/C++/java in windows

Tags: vim, ide

I found some source about how to configure gvim as a ide on **linux**,
but I don't have the configuration On **Windows**. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's really pretty similar, the only changes I have in my vimrc for Windows are this:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim 
behave mswin
```

If I recall correctly this makes a few small changes, like changing ctrl-v (block select) to ctrl-q since ctrl-v is used as paste on Windows.  There are a few other things, like using set guioptions to change the behavior of the menu bar.  I use these commands in Windows to turn off all the menu bars, but you can customize it how you want.

```
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=r
```

You can check :help behave and :help guioptions for more info from within gvim.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VIM to do C++ and Java, I'd seriously look at using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). The refactoring and code management capabilities are far in advance of aything that VIM will have.

I'm speaking as a VIM diehard, btw. I didn't give up on the power of VIM within Eclipse. I run [VIPlugIn](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) within Eclipse and that works very well (and is worth paying for). I still use VIM for adhoc work, and it's available on *any* machine I encounter, but for serious productive development the modern IDEs are the way forward.